# What is the PS4 Launch Edition?

Tags: ps4

I am looking to buy a PS4 from the Sony Website. While I was browsing the internet, I saw mention of the PS4 Launch Edition - though I didn't see this on Sony's site. It seemed much more expensive, but I can't figure out why. What's different between the 'launch edition' and an ordinary PS4?

Comment: please tell me all diffrences, if you can. doesnt matter if its a small diffrence, please still tell it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launch Edition PS4s were guaranteed to ship on the day of the launch. The product itself is in every way identical to other PS4s.